# Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm working on a react-native and I need to upload an image to Firebase using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start). I'm using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker) to select the image from the phone which gives me the base64 encoded data.

When I try to upload the image to Firebase it gives me the error `Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found` but I already checked if the string is a valid base64 string with regex and it is!

I already read a few answers from here but I tried all that. Here's my code:

```
function uploadImage(image){
  const user = getCurrentUser();
  const refImage = app.storage().ref(`profileImages/${user.uid}`);

  refImage.putString(image, 'base64').then(() => {
    console.log('Image uploaded');
  });
}
```

The image picker:

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(ImageOptions, (response) => {
  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    uploadImage(response.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm doing the exact same thing and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @activelogic I ended up using react-native-fetch-blob to upload a blob instead of base64 string

Comment: I get this error, but only in the emulator. It works fine in production mode. Stripping the beginning gives a "not a valid data-url" error, so that's not it.

Answer (score 14):

if `image` is a base64 data URL you can use 'data_url' parameter and metadata:

```
function uploadImage(image){
  const user = getCurrentUser();
  const refImage = app.storage().ref(`profileImages/${user.uid}`);

  refImage.putString(image, 'data_url', {contentType:’image/jpg’}).then(() => {
    console.log('Image uploaded');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to remove this string from your image variable `"data:image/jpeg;base64,`.
need `only data`

Comment: I did that as well, no luck. But i ended up uploading the image using a blob

Comment: @corasan would you mind uploading your code for the blob? i'm in the exact same situation you're in

Answer (score 5):

**image.substring(23)**

```
function uploadImage(image){
      const user = getCurrentUser();
      const refImage = app.storage().ref(`profileImages/${user.uid}`);

      refImage.putString(image.substring(23), 'base64').then(() => {
        console.log('Image uploaded');
      });
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't work in all situations, like when content type is `image/png` instead of `image/jpeg` . Like I said in my answer, I think split is a simpler and more consistent way of doing it

Answer (score 4):

I use split().

```
function uploadImage(image){
  const user = getCurrentUser();
  const refImage = app.storage().ref(`profileImages/${user.uid}`);

  refImage.putString(image.split(',')[1], 'base64').then(() => {
    console.log('Image uploaded');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used google bucket url instead of using `firebase/storage` api, and `expo-file-system` package to load the image/video from the mobile phone to firebase. Here is my code:

```js
const sendPhotoOrVideo = () => {
    FileSystem.uploadAsync(
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=FILE_NAME',
      'FILE_LOCATION',
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            'Bearer YOUR_OAUTH2_TOKEN',
        },
      },
    )
}
```

FileSystem.uploadAsync comes from `expo-file-system` package. 'FILE_LOCATION' fetched using `expo-image-picker` package.